# Toast when checked in custom adapter listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want when I checked on check box the code returns string of text view that's in the same row only.

I'm using LayoutInflater and another class which has code for creating list containing strings.

My code :

```
 public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<model> {


private final List<model> list;
  private final Activity context;

  public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rep, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;

  }


  static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
      }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
          view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rep, null);
          final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TextView07);
          viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox05);
          viewHolder.checkbox
              .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                  model element = (model) viewHolder.checkbox
                      .getTag();
                  element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                }
              });
          view.setTag(viewHolder);
          viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
          view = convertView;
          ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;


      }
}
```

my xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/h103"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="27dp"
android:layout_x="0dp"
android:layout_y="0dp"
android:background="@drawable/back1" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox05"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:button="@drawable/test" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-6dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:text="095110263" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: read first line of my post :) .

Answer (score 0):

You have to work on checkbox.onclicklistener rather then checkbox.onCheckedChanged because if you uses it in list view then it will automatically called then your checked check box will hide out.

```
    new OnClickListener()
    {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view)
         {}
    }
```

in onclicklistener, you get view as parameter which is a check box. here view has a method of getparent() which returns you a view in which your check box is set. you can check it by printing in log. if u got parent of check box then u can also get all child views of parent in which 1 child view is check box. from all child views u can get there values to show them in toast. if check box's parent has another parent in view of list item then u can also get parent of parent view by calling a getparent() method.

Please keep in mind that views have parent child relation so if you wants all child then you have to get parent.

Comment: I think there are sol easier form this ,,

Comment: Please share your solution. It may help me while writing good and distributed code.

Answer (score 0):

First Add 1 button at bottom of ur list view btnOk

```
btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();


                 ArrayList<model> almodel = adapter.almodel;
                 responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

                 for(int i=0;i<almodel.size();i++)
                 {
                     model m = almodel.get(i);
                     if(m.isSelected())
                     {

                      responseText.append("\n" + m.getName());

                     }

                  }


         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```